# Ajax.BeginForm Update unique div id in For Loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

**Update**
I ended up just using Session Variables to pass in the values to the Ajax.BeginForm block.  It's a hack that I didn't want to use, but I just couldn't find another way...

**Original Post**
I am using a For Loop that assigns each comment div in the loop a unique id like:

```
<div id="comment@(feedModel.PostID)"></div>
```

EX:

comment1

comment2

comment3

Each one of these div's has an Ajax.BeginForm with a input submit button.  I want to set the UpdateTargetId AjaxOption, but I can't because each id is unique.  So UpdateTargetId = "div" won't work.  I can't just pass in the model or TempData becasue this is Ajax.BeginForm.  So how do I pass in the feedModel.PostID?

Code:

```
@foreach (Website.Models.FeedModel feedModel in Model)
{
    <span id="commentspan@(feedModel.PostID)" style="margin-top:5px;    display:block; 
        font-weight:bold"><a href="#" onclick="loadPartialView(@feedModel.PostID);   
        return false;">Comments(@feedModel.Replies)</a></span>
    <div id="comments@(feedModel.PostID)"></div>
```

}

The Javascript that is called:

```
 function loadPartialView(context) {
 method HomeController._Comments
 $('#comments' + context).load('Home/_Comments/' + context);
}
```

Inside that PartialView

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{   
<div class="childpost">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitChildPost", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = 
"comments@TempData['feedModelID'].ToString()" }, new { id = 
@TempData["feedModelID"].ToString() }))
{
    @Html.TextArea("MessageBox", "", 2, 50, null)
    <br />
    <p>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="replybutton" />
    </p>
}
</div>
}
```

Which posts to the Action.  The string id is null because you can't pass Model values or Temp Data to the Ajax.BeginForm so I'm not sure what to do...

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SubmitChildPost(FormCollection formValue, string id)
    {
        string message = formValue["MessageBox"].ToString();

        if (message != "")
        {
            MessageRepository.UpdatePostReply(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            MessageRepository.SaveChildPost(message, id, User.Identity.Name);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("_Comments", "Home",  new { ID = id});
    }
```

Comment: FYI, for future reference, putting a hyphen in front of the @ works "comments-@(feedModel.PostID)".  Run across this all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Ajax.BeginForm` is inside of the `For` loop, you can give the target div a unique id using the same method you already are using, like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Comment", "Comments", new AjaxOptions() 
    { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "target" + feedModel.PostID }))
```

Then, in your loop, define the target div:

```
<div id="target@feedModel.PostID" />
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the code you posted, making an assumption that the `context` value you are passing is being passed into the id tokenvalue in your route, then you can capture this value in the PartialView as follows:

```
@{
    var id = this.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
}
```

Then, you can use `id` to assign your unique id.

Comment: If I use HTML.BeginForm that would work, but with Ajax.BeginForm feedModel.PostID is null.

Comment: Please post some sample code to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not having any problem getting data in the partialview.  I have the model in the partial view and I can access the model just fine.  I just can't access it inside the Ajax.BeginForm block.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out.